# CRM Api FetchXml replaces characters when using like

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I'm trying to call CRM Api to fetch contacts. The requirement says I can search by name using the LIKE operator.

I'm using the fetchxml below to query CRM:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"> 
  <entity name="contact"> 
    <attribute name="fullname" /> 
    <filter type="and"> 
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" /> 
    </filter> 
    <filter type="and"> 
      <condition attribute="fullname" operator="like" value="%ben%" /> 
    </filter>
  </entity> 
</fetch>
```

The problem is: If I try with "test" for example, it works fine. But if I try to search for "ben" it doesn't. I believe the issue is related to encoding but I can't find a way to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have Ben record with active StateCode?

Comment: Absolutely yes and if I search for his surname the query returns his contact details. I think its because %be gets replaced with something, not sure.

Comment: Nothing jumps out as wrong here, but how did you create this fetch?  I generally recommend using advanced find, then exporting the definition.  And can you add the code to ensure its nothing related to how you are using this query in your js or c#?

Comment: It might be interesting to try it as a QueryExpression or LINQ to see what happens.

Comment: I created the advanced find then downloaded the definition as
`<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="fullname" operator="like" value="%be%" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>`

Comment: The I encoded it as
`"%3Cfetch%20version='1.0'%20output-format='xml-platform'%20mapping='logical'%20distinct='false'%3E%0D%0A%3Centity%20name='contact'%3E%0D%0A%3Cattribute%20name='fullname'%20/%3E%0D%0A%3Cattribute%20name='telephone1'%20/%3E%0D%0A%3Cattribute%20name='contactid'%20/%3E%0D%0A%3Corder%20attribute='fullname'%20descending='false'%20/%3E%0D%0A%3Cfilter%20type='and'%3E%0D%0A%3Ccondition%20attribute='fullname'%20operator='like'%20value='%25be%25'%20/%3E%0D%0A%3C/filter%3E%0D%0A%3C/entity%3E%0D%0A%3C/fetch%3E%0D%0A"`

Comment: But when I try to run it like `https://<yourorg>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/contacts?fetchXml=encodedFetchXML` as mentioned by @ArunVinoth the `value='%25be%25'` bit becomes `value=%27%25be%25%27`

Comment: @JosephDuty I would like to post the code I'm using but it doesn't fit in the comment box...

Comment: Did you reach out to Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like encoding error in your code. Try to pass your encoded fetchxml query in the below url & test in the browser address bar. If it results the expected record(s) then it’s not platform problem.

```
https://<yourorg>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/contacts?fetchXml=encodedFetchXML
```

> To use FetchXml, we need to format FetchXml in usable Web API service
>   endpoint format. We do this by storing the FetchXML in a variable and
>   encoding the string with the encodeURI function native to JavaScript as
>   below.
>
> `var encodedFetchXml = encodeURI(fetchContact);`

[Read more](https://arvindcsit.blog/2018/01/10/retrieve-data-using-web-api-and-fetchxml/)

**Update**:
I tested this. Both the below fetch filter worked & gave me the expected `contact` record in browser test.

```
<condition attribute="lastname" operator="like" value="%thiy%" />

<condition%20attribute="lastname"%20operator="like"%20value=%27%25thiy%25%27%20/>
```

**Edit:**

We faced this issue in our Production application today when users trying to search for `%bernhard%`, but we are handling in code with `value="%%bbbernhard%"` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @ArunVinoth for your answer. Please see my comments above.

Comment: @EFX see my updated answer. Also edit the question & add your code as Joseph said. Are you crm online or onpremise?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2016
(8.0.1.79) (DB 8.0.1.79) on premise. I can't find where to edit the question (oh man this is embarassing!)
Anyway, have you tried with the string '%be%'? I think the problem is the %be bit because with other names it works fine.

Comment: @EFX you are right. to get it working I tried with %bbben%, only this returns name contains ben :). Report it to Microsoft. you found a bug.. lol